# Where can I find the configuration for KMail?

Tags: linux, email, kde, kmail

I am using KMail 1.12.1 and KDE 4.3.2 on Linux 2.6. Does anybody out there know where to find the configuration files for it? The intention behind that is to share these files on more than one computer using a version control system, e.g. subversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the **kmailrc** file. Just do a locate or find from a terminal window.

You might also want to have a look at the [KMail Handbook](http://docs.kde.org/kde3/en/kdepim/kmail/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's it. My configuration file was located here:
~/.kde/share/config/kmailrc

Comment: Using kmail (kmail-4.14.10-7) on Fedora 22 (`konsole --version` says this is "KDE Frameworks: 5.16.0"). The file `.kde/share/config/kmailrc` only contains one line. The [FAQ](https://userbase.kde.org/KMail/FAQs_Hints_and_Tips#Transfer_mail_and_settings_to_another_computer_.28or_another_user_account_on_the_same_machine.29) indicates a lot of files (which are dsitribution-dependent) that are involved, so there is more to this now.